# Where to start in creating Database?

Tags: database

A friend of mine is a property manager and rents out units in building. currently everything is in folder and he is looking to have them in computer (Database).

I want to help him since I think I do good in programming and I have good Mysql knowledge (CRUD). However, I am not sure about the starting point so I have 2 questions:

1- In terms of hardware, do I just install mysql server on his computer? Or do I get him t buy another computer and have mysql on it (so it is standalone server)? Or do I need some specialized server for DB?

2- Are there certain steps (high level bullet points would do as I would take it from there) I need to follow? Or even if you can recommend a link I can read?

I have knowledge with Mysql, Java, C++, and PHP

Thank you
Ahmad

Comment: If his sever needs to be online at all times purchase a cheap host and store his information in a mysql database then run backups on the database so you can add in records, tables from your local machine using xampp etc.

Comment: hmmm good point actually, I assume you are talking about online webhost, right? Is there a specific webhost for DB or can any webhosting company (such as goDaddy) be ok for such requirement?

Comment: If it has to be used from several workstations, instead of buying a "computer", you can buy a NAS, like those made by Synology. Its's cheaper, incredibly stable, and has MySql built in.
To administer, use Adminer (http://www.adminer.org/), much nicer than phpMySql IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try someone like [site5](http://www.site5.com/), [hostgator](http://www.hostgator.com/shared.shtml) for cheap/good hosting but not godaddy since their interface is usually for people who do not code. Also if you're on a mac install the site locally using [mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html), or [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for windows and then export the database to a live server which can cost anywhere from $5-$15/month.